# Handling order by and order type parameters in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

In order to avoid SQL injection I made some researched and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php#answer-60496) answer I started to use MySQLi prepared statemets. It all went fine until I got into the `order by` and `order type` parameters which are sent from the frontend based on what the user clicks. To be more specific I have some tables with some headers and user can arrange the data considering name, price, date, etc and also he can choose between `ASC` or `DESC`. I store this into some input type hidden so I guess that they might be able to change that using `firebug`. Because of this I need to be sure that they can't inject anything into my database.

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 ORDER BY ? ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['order_by'], $_GET['order_type']);
```

It seems that I get an error. I did some researches and somebody said that there is no solution for this, another person said that the only solution is hardcoded and another person said that I have to quit using prepared statements and try `mysql_real_escape_string` but in the answer that I linked somebody say:

> If you're using a recent version of PHP, the mysql_real_escape_string
> option outlined below will no longer be available

So I gueess this is not the way also. So my question remains, what should I do next? Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: You can only use parameters for values, you can't use them to substitute table and column names.

Comment: The reason `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't available is because the `mysql` extension is gone. But if you're using `mysqli` it has `mysqli_real_escape_string`. But that's not useful for this, because it's for escaping strings, not column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use parameters for column names, only for values. Just check that the column names are valid.

```
$allowed_order_by = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', ...);
$allowed_order_type = array('asc', 'desc', '');
if (in_array(strtolower($_GET['order_by']), $allowed_order_by) &&
    in_array(strtolower($_GET['order_type']), $allowed_order_type)) {
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM mytable 
        ORDER BY {$_GET['order_by']} {$_GET['order_type']}");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: `$_GET['order_ty[e]` is throwing off syntax highlighting. You may have meant `$_GET['order_type']`

Comment: I would have but TBH, wasn't entirely sure of what could have been another array.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not allow parameters for column aliases, expressions, or keywords.  You need to plug them directly into the query:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 ORDER BY '.$_GET['order_by'].' '.$_GET['order_type');
```

If these are being provided by a user, you should validate them before putting them into the query string.

Comment: If I have to validate them before by my self why should I use prepared statemets after all? ..since they does not handle that instead of me?

Comment: @paulalexandru Use a prepared statement if the query has other parameters.

Comment: @Barmar - Why other parameters? Why not all the parameters? This parameters came from the user side, he can edit them if he wants.

Comment: I mean parameters that are normal values, such as `WHERE username = '$_GET['user']'`. This should be done with `bind_param`.

Comment: @paulalexandru . . . Simple answer:  these are not parameters.  Parameters in SQL replace constants, not table names, column names, functions names, or keywords.  That is just how the language was invented.